# Secure SSL / HTTPS API call with PHP

Tags: php, ssl, curl, https, protocols

In reference to this previous question:
[Connect through HTTPS instead of HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13606509/connect-through-https-instead-of-http)

Would this be the good way to make a secure API call with `HTTPS`?

```
public function demo(){
    $Username = 'username';
    $Password = 'xxxxxxxxx';
    $url = 'http://api.text-connect.co.uk/api/api.php?Username='.$Username.'&Password='.$Password.'&Action=checkcredits';


    $ch = curl_init($url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,  2);


    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    echo $result;
}
```

Should i use `https` instead of `http` at the `$url` variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you use an `https://...` URL, no HTTPS secured connection will be established.

The `_SSL_` options you are setting only specify the behavior *in case an HTTPS connection is made*. They don't turn an HTTP URL into an HTTPS URL.

Comment: When use `https` on my `$url` variable it doesn't work anymore. Why is that? Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not a detailed enough problem description to be able to help.

Comment: It keeps loading and finally it shows this message `Error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded`. Doesn't look good... with `http` it works fast. What any other information you need to be able to help me?

Comment: After changing the execution limit time it shows `$result` with a `false` value.

Comment: Open a new question with as many information as you can provide. The comments to an accepted answer are not the place to debug this.

Comment: I have opened another one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13644280/failing-to-connect-through-https-and-curl-at-php